# Java. Олимпиадное программирование. ACMP номер 184

Tags: java, алгоритм

Не проходит 2ой тест в задаче 184, что за тест - неизвестно([Рабочее время](https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=12&id_topic=8&id_problem=41)). Программа на Java, прокомментировал некоторые моменты.

Тест в примере проходит. 

Кастомный тест тоже проходит:

`6 
18.11. 15:13 
29.05. 13:27 
18.06. 15:13 
18.06. 10:27 
18.12. 10:19 
03.11. 15:42`

Ответ: `1496:38` 
Сама программа:

```
package com.company.Sort;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WorkTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
        int K = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        Integer[][] lists = new Integer[K][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < K; i++){ // парсинг input.txt в двумерный массив. Структура: 0 - день; 1 - месяц; 2 - час; 3 - минута
            String[] sinp = scan.nextLine().split("\\. |:|\\.| ");
            int input[] = Arrays.stream(sinp).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            lists[i][0] = input[0];
            lists[i][1] = input[1];
            lists[i][2] = input[2];
            lists[i][3] = input[3];
        }
        lists = Arrays.stream(lists).sorted((x1,x2) -> { // сортировка по возрастанию даты
            if (x1[1] != x2[1]){
                return x1[1] - x2[1];
            } else if (x1[0] != x2[0]){
                return x1[0] - x2[0];
            } else {
                if (x1[2] != x2[2])
                    return x1[2] - x2[2];
                else
                    return x1[3] - x2[3];
            }
        }).toArray(Integer[][]::new);
        int middle; // дни между первым и последним (если есть)
        int[] days_per_month = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}; // кол-во дней в месяцах года
        Integer[] prev_note; // заметка первого дня (просто инфа о первом дне, с той же структурой даты и времени )
        Integer[] next_note; // заметка последнего дня
        int total_min = 0;
        int prev_day;
        int next_day;
        // Структура: 0 - день; 1 - месяц; 2 - час; 3 - минута
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i+=2){
            middle = 0; // дни между первым и последним (если есть)
            prev_note = lists[i];
            next_note = lists[i+1];
            prev_day = 18*60 - (prev_note[2]*60 + prev_note[3]) + 1; // кол-во часов в первый день
            next_day = (next_note[2] - 10)*60 + next_note[3]; // в последний
            if (prev_note[1] != next_note[1]) { // если в разных месяцах, учитывается middle
                for (int j = prev_note[1]; j <= next_note[1]; j++) {
                    if (j == prev_note[1])
                        middle += days_per_month[j - 1] - prev_note[0];
                    else if (j == next_note[1])
                        middle += next_note[0] - 1;
                    else
                        middle += days_per_month[j - 1];
                }
                total_min += middle * 8 * 60;
                total_min += prev_day + next_day;
            } else { // если в одном месяце
                if (prev_note[0] != next_note[0]) {  // если в разных днях
                    total_min += (next_note[0] - prev_note[0] - 1) * 8;
                    total_min += prev_day + next_day;
                }
                else  //один день
                    total_min += next_note[2] * 60 + next_note[3] - prev_note[2] * 60 - prev_note[3];
            }
        }
        int hours = total_min / 60;
        int min = total_min - hours * 60;
        pw.print(hours + ":" + ((min < 10) ? "0" + min: min) );
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

UPD: Если вам не нравится то, как написан код, или, допустим, где-нибудь можно было сделать короче - пишите, буду благодарен.

Comment: тоесть алгоритм примерно следующий: прочитать даты, отсортировать, брать по 2 даты ,считать разность и всё суммировать,так?

Comment: @VladMamaev грубо говоря - да

Comment: сделать короче можно было используя для хранения записей класс LocalDateTime, static метод LocalDate.parse() для создания записей, LocalDateTime.compareTo() для сортировки, и класс Duration и метод Duration.between() для подсчета разности между двумя LocalDateTime

Comment: Сортировать записи не нужно. Достаточно сложить все концы и вычесть все начала из общей суммы. Это даст ответ.